# Menu that Scrolls with Horizontal Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I was attempting to make a horizontal smooth-scrolling one-page website.

I would like a menu that scrolls with the horizontal page to slide into 
view everytime a new page is in focus.

Here's an example of the scrolling script I was going for,
I can't seem to figure out how to make it horizontal though.
http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating.html

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: The page you link to does scroll horizontally, it is linked by absolute locations. What are you looking to mimic actually?

Comment: Why not do a fixed position menu? It would depend on how you're setting up the horizontal sliding though...

Comment: That menu works both ways. Try setting your browser window really small and magnifying the text, then scrolling sideways - the menu will follow horizontally.

Comment: -JM4 I understand it's not horizontal, I was hoping to achieve the same effect as the vertical scrolling menu, but horizontal.

@AllenZ. I see, thanks. Can I simply use this with a smooth scrolling page like http://www.sursly.com/horizontal.html

Comment: You may find this answer usefull : [horizontal page sliding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414642/responsive-horizontal-page-sliding-navigation/24465646#24465646)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource you referenced is simply a text box, you would design your own navigation within, maybe something like this for example, or your own tab menu

```
<div>
    <a href="#">nav item 1</a> | <a href="#">nav item 2</a> | <a href="#">nav item 3</a>
</div>
```

You will notice that there is the following code block in the style element of the div

```
width:200px;height:50px;
```

This is where you would change the size to say

```
width:800px;height:30px;
```

to make it horizontal.

Just read the page that explains how to use it and you should be right.

I hope this gets you going in the right direction.